# Flex wrap add extra space when it wraps to multiple lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have a flex with `flex-wrap: wrap`. The container only takes content width when all items fits in one line. However when it wraps to multiple lines, it adds extra space on the right side. I tried `inline-flex` with `align-content: flex-start` but no luck.

How can I make it that container of item's width is just fit to them width adding extra padding?

On below link sample (my laptop screen), if I have up to 3 item divs(2 items on the first line and 3rd item on second line), it is fine but when I add fourth item div(first & second items on the first line and 3rd and fourth items on second line), padding is being added automatically.

```css
.grandparent {
  display: flex;
}

.toggle {
  display: none;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px dotted green;
  padding: 10px
}

.icondiv {
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="toggle">Toggle</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="item">first</div>
      <div class="item">second</div>
      <div class="item">third</div>
      <div class="item">fourth</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icondiv">Icon div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [CodePen Sample Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zXRVez)

Comment: you mean without adding extra padding?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work according to what you need:

```css
.grandparent {display:flex;}
.toggle {display: none;}
.main {
  display: flex; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 604px !important;
  height: 70px !important;
}
.grandparent, .parent .main, .item{ 
  width: 300px; 
  border: 1px dotted green; 
  position: relative; 
  float:left !important;
 
}
.grandparent, .icondiv { width: 800px; border: 1px solid #333;}
```

```html
<div class="grandparent">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="toggle">Toggle</div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="item">first</div>
      <div class="item">second</div>         
      <div class="item">third</div>
      <div class="item">fourth</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="icondiv">Icon div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However your solution stack items vertically. I want items to only wrap when horizontal space run out. If you look at my codepen sample, first & second items are on the first line and third & fourth items are on the second line. That is what I want(without extra padding on the right).

Comment: @whtflower ahh in that case you can set main container width to fit the two items inside with padding only from right, wait I will update my answer

Comment: @whtflower check updated answer, it should be like that?

Comment: parent container(.main) shouldn't have initial width/height. I want it to be flexible to fit items. it need to be determined with items size.